# awk - Group by and sum column values

Tags: awk, pipe, ps

I have command to list system process by memory usage:

```
ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem
```

Which list a table like

```
COMMAND         %MEM
firefox         28.2
chrome           5.4
compiz           4.8
atom             2.5
chrome           2.3
Xorg             2.3
skype            2.2
chrome           2.0
chrome           1.9
atom             1.9
nautilus         1.8
hud-service      1.5
evince           1.3
```

I would like to get total memory share per programs instead of per process of same programs. So I could get output like

```
COMMAND         %MEM
firefox         28.2
chrome          11.6
compiz           4.8
atom             4.4
Xorg             2.3
skype            2.2
nautilus         1.8
hud-service      1.5
evince           1.3
```

I thought about using `awk`, which I don't know much. Ended up with something like:

```
ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | awk -F "\t" '
{processes[$0] += $1;}
{End
for(i in processes) {
  print i,"\t",processes[i];
}
}'
```

But it didn't work.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`processes[$0] += $1;` use the whole line as key in your associative array, which is not unique. You must use `$1`, which is command name as key.

Try:

```
$ ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | awk '
  NR == 1 { print; next }
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "%-15s\t%s\n", i, a[i];
    }
  }
'
```

If you want to sort the output by the second field, try:

```
$ ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | awk '
  NR == 1 { print; next }
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "%-15s\t%s\n", i, a[i] | "sort -rnk2";
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: Sorry, that `if` was typing mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: It seems to be working. Will it be possible to have sorted by second column (Memory) in ascending order?

Comment: Wondering how `sort` statement along with `printf` decide the sorting :) weird!

Comment: @cuonglm, How I can add one more column cpu in this command.

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working for me (was producing a single line of incorrect output) and then I realized the original input had a line of column names and mine did not.  I removed the `NR == 1`  line and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

cuonglm answer solves your typo, to get the values in **ascending** order (as asked in your comment), pipe the output through `sort -n -k 2` (sort as numbers (`-n`, on second field (`-k 2`), after changing the print statement to output the floats as in your example:

```
$ ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem | awk '
  NR == 1 { print; next }
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "%-15s\t%.1f\n", i, a[i];
    }
  }
' | sed 's/%MEM/-1MEM/' | sort -n -k 2 | sed 's/-1MEM/%MEM/'
```

Output (using your table as input instead of doing `ps` on my system):

```
COMMAND         %MEM
evince          1.3
hud-service     1.5
nautilus        1.8
skype           2.2
Xorg            2.3
atom            4.4
compiz          4.8
chrome          11.6
firefox         28.2
```

Alternatively you can pipe the output through this python program (if you want descending sort (as in your example), change the `reverse=False` into `reverse=True`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import operator

d = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        name, val = line.split()
        val = float(val)
        d.setdefault(name, [0.0])[0] += val
    except ValueError:
        print line,

for x in sorted(d.items(), reverse=False, key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print "{:16s}{:>4}".format(x[0], x[1][0])
```

Comment: This will break the header line.

Comment: @cuonglm What do you mean by that? It stays on one line and is at the top.

Comment: Did you actually run `ps -A --sort -rss -o comm,pmem` in your machine? Something like `acpid           0` compare with `COMMAND         %MEM` can break the result

Comment: @cuonglm I had not, I see the problem is you printed the float values as strings. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Anthon Header line get printed at wrong place.

Comment: @Junaid For some reason `sort -n` puts any non-digit string between 0.0 and other values. I cludge it more, but the python solution is even more elegant now.